# Element from Galois group of L over F permutes the elements of a set of coset representatives

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I have a group $G = \mathrm{Gal}(L/F)$ and a subgroup $H \leq G$ which corresponds to the intermediate field $K$, I believe that there exists a set $A$ of coset representatives for $H$ in $G$.  In other words, there is a set $A = \{a_1H, a_2H, ..., a_mH\}$ which represents all of the cosets of $H$ in $G$.

If I have this, and I take some automorphism $\sigma \in G$ why is it that applying this automorphism to $A$ essentially just permutes the elements?  In other words, I believe that $\sigma(A) = A$ but I don't know why this is the case.

In other words, I guess I'm asking why $\sigma(a_iH) = a_jH$ since all we know about $\sigma$ is that it is an automorphism which fixes $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact a problem of group theory and the notion of group action. The fact that the groups you consider arise from Galois theory is irrelevant for the statement to hold.

> Let $G$ be any group together with $H$ any subgroup. Then $G$ acts by left multiplication on the set $G/H$ of cosets of $H$ in $G$.

This statement means that we have a group homomorphism $\rho:G\to \mathfrak S(G/H)$ which is described by left multiplication. That is, an element $g$ acts on the coset $aH$ by sending it to $(ga)H$.

In order to verify the claim, one must check that **(1)** the arrow $G\to \mathfrak S(G/H)$ is well defined and that **(2)** it is a group homomorphism.

**(1)** Let $g\in G$. We define a function $G/H \to G/H$ by sending a coset $aH$ to the coset $(ga)H$. This is a well defined function, as it does not depend on the choice of the coset representative $a$. Indeed, if $a'$ is another representative, then we have
$$(ga')H = g(a'H) = g(aH) = (ga)H$$
Moreover, this function has an inverse : it is the function sending a coset $aH$ to $(g^{-1}a)H$. Thus, our function is in fact an element of $\mathfrak S(G/H)$, that is a permutation of the set $G/H$. We have just defined a map $\rho:G\to \mathfrak S(G/H)$. In more explicit terms, we have $\rho(g)(aH) = (ga)H$ for all $g,a \in G$.

**(2)** We must check that our map $\rho$ is compatible with the product in $G$ and composition in $\mathfrak S(G/H)$ ; that is one must check $\rho(gg') = \rho(g)\circ \rho(g')$ for every $g,g'\in G$. To check this, we evaluate both functions on a given coset $aH$. On the one hand we have
$$\rho(gg')(aH) = (gg'a)H$$
and on the other hand, we have
$$\rho(g)\circ\rho(g')(aH) = \rho(g)\left((g'a)H\right) = \left(g(g'a)\right)H$$
And both terms are equal (associativity of the multiplication in $G$). As it is true for all $a$, both maps are equal and $\rho$ really is a group homomorphism.